# Change Acronyms header to match list of tables/List of figures (glossaries)

Tags: table-of-contents, glossaries

I'm using Overleaf to write my thesis. I want to format my list of tables/list of figures and add them to the table of contents. Most of the following code is copy and paste from other answers on this forum.

However, now that I need to add a list of abbreviation, I want the style of the header of this list to be similar to that of the list of tables/list of figures. I honestly don't know what I'm doing to change the style of the LoF/LoT, but I want to do the same to the acronyms. I'm using the following code to do that.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openany]{book} %oneside
\textheight23cm \textwidth15cm

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    

    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
    \fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\usepackage[acronym, toc]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{abms}{ABMS}{Agent-Based Modeling and Simulation}
\renewcommand{\acronymname}{List of Abbreviations}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

% Headings for every page of ToC, LoF and Lot
\newcommand\tocheading{\par\bigskip\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}\hfill Page\par}
\newcommand\lofheading{\par\bigskip\figurename\hfill Page\par}
\newcommand\lotheading{\par\bigskip\MakeUppercase{\tablename}\hfill Page\par}

% Centering titles for the ToC, Lof and Lot
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill}

\begin{document}
\clearpage
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\printglossaries

\clearpage
\addtocontents{lof}{\lofheading}% add heading to the first page in LoF
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\addtocontents{lot}{\lotheading}% add heading to the first page in LoT
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Latex! Here is a way to achieve that. I made some changes to your code. And I need explain some of this changes. You might still be confused after these explanations. I recommend you take some time to read some basic latex document. It may help you a lot:

> Edit: I need correct one of my statements in third item. see below:

1. If you wanna a oneside document you should use `oneside` option instead the `openany`
2. I generate the real figure and table, you don't need manually add entries to lof or lot.
3. Because you use `\makeglossaries`, So `glossaries` package will use `makeindex` (which is CLI application) to sort the entries. Generally, every time you compile your document you need manually run makeindex (more infomation see [glossaries](https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) document page.21). In case you don't know what is this mean. You should add `automake` to `glossaries` package option.  <s>And `\makeglossaries` command should be added after all the `\newacronym` have been defined.</s> This was wrong. Actually, the opposite way is correct which means `\makeglossaries` command should be added before all the `\newacronym` have been defined.
4. Because you use `fancyhdr` package, your `headheight` is too small. So I set `\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}`

> Some recommendation: You could use `geometry` package to set your margin instead of setting `\textheight23cm` and `\textwidth15cm`. Because it's easy and straight forward for new user.

> Base on your comments, I write the answer here:

1. On Overleaf, it is impossible to execute commands using CLI. But overleaf take care of everything for you. You can take a look this [link](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Glossaries).
2. To understand the meaning of that command you can go to `tocloft` package [document](https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf) page.23. This two command `\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont\MakeUppercase}` and `\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}` did similar thing as `\hfill\normalfont\MakeUppercase your header\hfill` means centering the "your header" and make it using normal font and uppercase letter.
3. `\makeglossary` command don't have any parameters to set your "List of Abbreviations" header. What I did to set it is through `\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={\centering\normalsize\normalfont\MakeUppercase{\acronymname}},toctitle=\acronymname]`. To see more informations about this you can check the [document](https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) at page.182.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}% oneside option added
\textheight23cm \textwidth15cm % better use geometry package (e.g. \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry})
\usepackage{mwe} %create fake figure
\usepackage{lipsum} %create fake text

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\usepackage[acronym,toc,automake]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{abms}{ABMS}{Agent-Based Modeling and Simulation}
\renewcommand{\acronymname}{List of Abbreviations}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

% Centering titles for the ToC, Lof and Lot
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill}

\begin{document}
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\listoffigures
\clearpage

\listoftables

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={\centering\normalsize\normalfont\MakeUppercase{\acronymname}},toctitle=\acronymname]

\chapter{Foo}
This is an example of abbreviation \gls{abms}.

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Table Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
    \begin{tabular}{lccc}
        \hline
        items&a&b&c\\\hline
        item1&1&2&3\\
        item2&4&5&6\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanation. That solved it. however, I have a few follow up questions of you'd allow me.

1. regarding your third comment, you mentioned something about CLI, I'm using Overleaf, is it possible to execute commands using CLI using Overleaf?

Comment: 2. As I mentioned in my OP, most of the commands are copy and paste from other solutions, and not many people really explain how they achieve their results. I really try to understand what they did, but I fail to. For instance, the line ```\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont\MakeUppercase}```
I'm trying to understand what happened here, but I don't know where to look. The problem with Latex for me is that there are a lot of packages, each with its documentation, and I fail to find the correct info on the correct package. I hope you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: 3. I have been trying to use the command ```\makeglossary``` with parameters to adjust the styling like you did, but it failed in the past. not sure why it succeeded now.

Comment: @Ahmad I answer your questions by adding information in the answer. Check the new edit.

Comment: Thank you again. you've been very helpful

Comment: @Ahmad You are welcome!